# orthogonal projections and subspaces relations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $P$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $\mathcal{S}$ and let $Q$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathcal{T}$. Suppose $PQ = 0$.

1. Must $\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{T} = 0$?
2. Must $P$ and $Q$ commute?

Can anyone help me start this question please?

Comment: Please clarify all the definitions you are using.  Define orthogonal projection and what the multiplication of orthogonal projections mean.  Definitions will help you get started and also will help someone answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, a projection $P$ is orthogonal **iff** $P^* = P$.

So consider $0 = 0^* = (PQ)^* = Q^* P^* = Q P$. That is, $PQ=(PQ)^*$, hence $PQ$ is an orthogonal projection (and $Q,P$ commute).

From Part 1 of an earlier result [Orthogonal projection and two subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536664/orthogonal-projection-and-two-subspaces/536698#536698), we have ${\cal R}(PQ) = S \cap T$, hence $S \cap T = \{0\}$.