# when do orthogonal projection $\ P_UP_V = P_VP_U$

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

U, V are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space W,
Let $\ P_U$ and $\ P_V$ be the orthogonal projections onto U and V
respectively. When is it true that $\ P_UP_V = P_VP_U$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536664/4280 seems to answer your question.

Comment: I don't think they answer quite the same question. That question linked above answers this question when we know that $P_U P_V = P_{U\cap V}$, but we don't necessarily have that unless we have the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is true if and only if $U$ are $V$ are "perpendicular". By perpendicular, we mean the following:

Consider $U\cap V$ and its orthogonal complement in $U$, respectively $V$, denoted by $U_1$, $V_1$. We require that $U_1$ orthogonal to $V_1$ in the usual sense.