# Is it true that $\text{proj}_{U+W}=\text{proj}_U+\text{proj}_W-\text{proj}_{U\cap W}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let $V$ be a finitely generated real inner product space with $\dim V=n$ and inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$.

Let $U,W\subseteq V$ be sub-spaces of $V$. Is it true that we have
$$\text{proj}_{U+W}=\text{proj}_U+\text{proj}_W-\text{proj}_{U\cap W}$$
(where $\text{proj}_X:V\to V$ is the orthogonal projection onto the sub-space $X$)? After some attempts and some web searches, I was unable to find any information regarding this.

I want to say this is true. Let $\mathbf{u}=\{u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ and $\mathbf{w}=\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $W$. Either $U$ and $W$ intersect trivially or they don't. If they do intersect trivially, then we are done, since $\mathbf{u}\cup\mathbf{w}=\{u_1,\dots,u_m,w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ is a basis for $U+W$ and we can orthonormalize it using Grahm-Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_m,w_1',\dots,w_k'\}$ for $U+W$. In this case its clear that $$\text{proj}_{U+W}=\text{proj}_U+\text{proj}_W$$ since $\text{proj}_{U\cap W}$ is identically the zero operator on $V$.

Having some trouble in the more general case where the sub-spaces don't intersect trivially, mainly with notation and how to go about finding an orthogonal/orthonormal basis of $U\cap W$.

Maybe there is a better way to approach this problem or some better notation and someone may be able to offer some insight.

**Edit:**
As of Jyrki Lahtonen's counter example, the claim is false. Still open to new answers/perspectives and possibly some conditions which would allow for this to happen, if there are any.

Comment: You are on the right track but not quite. Start with a basis of $U \cap W$ and expan this basis to bases of $U$ and $W.$ Notice that the basis of $\{0\}$ is empty.

Comment: @WillM. so start with an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ of $U\cap W$ (assume non-empty for now). Extend to orthonormal bases $\{v_1,\dots,v_r,u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ of $U$ and $\{v_1,\dots,v_r,w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ of $W$. Then $\{u_1,\dots,u_m,w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ forms a basis of $U+W$. The basis for $U+W$ may not be orthonormal though, so run it through Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: The basis of $U + W$ _is_ orthonormal.

Comment: @WillM. oh? i guess im not seeing why. if it is then the conclusion is immediate. For example, how is it guaranteed that $u_1$ perpendicular to $w_1$ ?

Comment: You are right, it need not be. Construct a basis of$U \cap W$ then extend it orthonormally to a basis of $U$ and then to $U+W.$

Comment: alright. i’ll try working that way. thanks, starting with the basis of $U\cap W$ is a bit easier

Comment: I just did a rough sketch in my notebook but my last comment seems to be right. To grow the bases one at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false as stated.  Proffering a counterexample.

Let $V=\Bbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product. Let $U=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb{R}\}$ be the $x$-axis. Let $w=\{(t,t)\mid t\in\Bbb{R}\}$ be the line with slope one.
Then $U+W=V$ and $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

Consider the vector $\vec{x}=(3,1)$. Its projection to $U$ is $p_U(\vec{x})=(3,0)$. Its projection to $W$ is $p_W(\vec{x})=(2,2)$. Of course, its projection to $U\cap W$ is the zero vector and its projection to $V$ is itself.

But $\vec{x}\neq p_U(\vec{x})+p_W(\vec{x}).$

Comment: oh wow. nice counter example. wonder where my proof went wrong

Comment: one more follow up question if you don't mind. do you think that one can write $\text{proj}_{U+W}$ in terms of $\text{proj}_U$ and $\text{proj}_W$? possibly there are some conditions that allow for this to happen?

Comment: @CSquared Your recipe (and proof) works if we have direct sum decompositions $U=U'+ (U\cap W)$, $W=W'+(U\cap W)$ such that $U'\perp (U\cap W)$, $W'\perp (U\cap W)$ and
$U'\perp W'$. I didn't check, but it "feels" like this is the case when the two orthogonal projections commute: $p_U\circ p_W=p_W\circ p_U$. When that composition would also be equal to $p_{U\cap W}$. Sorry, I don't have time to think about this right now. May be later.

Comment: no worries. and thank you so much again, this was really helpful

Comment: May be start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536664/11619)? @CSquared

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on WillM.'s comments:

Choose an orthonormal basis $\mathbf{int}_{U,W}=\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ of $U\cap W$ (assuming they intersect non-trivially).

Extend this to an orthonormal basis $\mathbf{u}=\{v_1,\dots,v_r,u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ of $U$.

Further extend this to an orthornomal basis $\mathbf{sum}_{U,W}=\{v_1,\dots,v_r,u_1,\dots,u_m,w_1,\dots,w_l\}$ of $U+W$.

Note that $\mathbf{w}=\{v_1,\dots,v_r,w_1,\dots,w_l\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$.

Then we have
\begin{align*}
\text{proj}_{U}(x)+\text{proj}_{W}(x)-\text{proj}_{U\cap V}(x)
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^r\langle x,v_i\rangle v_i+\sum_{j=1}^m\langle x,u_j\rangle u_j\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}\langle x,v_i\rangle v_i+\sum_{k=1}^{l}\langle x,w_k\rangle w_k\right)-\sum_{i=1}^r\langle x,v_i\rangle v_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^r\langle x,v_i\rangle v_i+\sum_{j=1}^m\langle x,u_j\rangle u_j+\sum_{k=1}^{l}\langle x,w_k\rangle w_k\\
&=\text{proj}_{U+W}(x)
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.

Comment: Why are $w_i$s orthogonal to $u_j$s?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had planned to extended them in such a manner to be orthonormal to each other.

Comment: I think a problem is that you cannot select the $w_i$s from $U^\perp\cap W$ as that intersection may have uncomfortably low dimension. You can extend an orthonormal basis of $U$ to an orthonormal basis of $U+W$, but there is no way to guarantee that basis would contain an orthonormal basis of $W$.

Comment: hmm. in my head i had thought of extending the bases using gram-schmidt or something similar so i didn't have to choose them from $U^{\perp}\cap W$, but that is the space where they would naturally lie in anyways.

Comment: The problem with that is that in Gram-Schmidt you may need to add something from $U$ to vectors from $W$, and end up outside of $W$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this is even false when the subspaces intersect trivially, as you have shown. guess i'm misunderstanding a couple of things. thanks for the counter example

Comment: Yeah, testing the claim with 1-dimensional subspaces already reveals a problem :-)

Comment: If $U \cap W =\{0\}$ but $U$ and $W$ are not orthogonal to each other (i.e. $\langle u, w\rangle =0$ for all $u\in U, w\in W$), you will not be able to find orthogonal bases of these two spaces such that the union of the two bases is still orthogonal.

Comment: If $U \cap W$ is not trivial, you can consider the orthogonal complements of $U\cap W$ in $U$ and $W$. Again, these complements need to be orthogonal if you want to find compatible orthogonal bases for $U\cap W$, $U$, $W$ and $U+W$.

Comment: Very interesting that my intuition was somewhat wrong. I did a rough sketch and I don't see an immediate flaw. You can still orthonormalise and the space spanned is the samem, but hey, you already gave a counterexample. So I am sure if I start digging what went wrong, I will find it. Thanks